# Ways to compute the n-the derivative of a discrete signal

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, derivative, derivation

This is a pretty general question about how to compute derivatives of a digital signal $x[n]$.

I would like to know what are the different approaches (from naive to complex) and how are they compared to one another? Is it possible with FIR/IIR filters? What are the pro's and contra's. Which are better for real-time applications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The estimation of derivative is straightforward:

$$x'(n)~=\frac{x(n+1)-x(n-1)}{2}$$

$$x''(n)~={x(n+1)-2*x({n})+x({n-1})}$$

or if you have a signal sampled at $t_i=i\Delta t$,
it is

$$x'(t_{i})~=\frac{x(t_{i+1})-x(t_{i-1})}{2*\Delta t}$$

$$x''(t_{i})~=\frac{x(t_{i+1})-2*x(t_{i})+x(t_{i-1})}{(\Delta t)^2}$$

What you are interested in may be how to smooth the estimation. And yes you can use some recursive filters such as  $y(n) = a \cdot x(n) + (1-a) \cdot y(n-1)$, or just implement your estimation with some simple windows (Hann window for example).

To achieve the high SNR without distorting the signal very much, [Savitzky–Golay filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_smoothing_filter) also smooths your data by fitting successive sub-sets of adjacent data points with a low-degree polynomial with linear least squares.

**EDIT**

Matlab code for an N-th derivative of signal row vector `x`

```
dx = x; %'Zeroth' derivative

for n = 1:N % Apply iteratively

    dif = diff(dx,1); % First derivative
    first = [dif(1) dif];
    last = [dif dif(end)];

    dx = (first+last)/2;
end
```

Comment: What is the n-th derivative then in the straightforward approach?

Comment: you can implement the 1st derivative iteratively. I'm not sure which programming language you are using, I added a simple implementation of N-th with Matlab for your reference. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is a good article in Wikipedia: [Numerical Differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation)

Since you'd expect differentiation to be (Anti?)symmetric, using IIR filters might not be the wisest of ideas.